# PHP variable to check ONLY LINK

Tags: php

I made a form where user post their product information and data. Information contain full name of the product, Manufacturers Name, Contact Address and Link of Manufacturers site. Now i know for validate the link we can use `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` php variable. Now the thing is let suppose if someone posted `https://www.google.com?page=bla+bla`, This `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` variable allows the url after `.com or .net or .org` etc. It means php variable allows the path here and URL validation not end here.

What i want is Do you guys know any php variable the can only validate the URL from https to `.com or .net or .org` etc and not allow the path like the example above.

EDIT: 
The list updates in the pdf format which can than be further access to whole company. Lets someone douche trying to put the wrong link thats why i need validation for the link.

Comment: Please edit your question on why you want to validate the link? What do you want to do with the link/URL? Why is it problematic that the URL contains a query string? Please describe more in detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Again, why is it important that `http://www.example.org/` is okay but `http://www.example.org/file.php?var=42` is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) returns an array containing the url's components. e.g.

```
var_dump( parse_url('https://www.google.com?page=bla+bla') );
```

outputs

```
array (size=3)
  'scheme' => string 'https' (length=5)
  'host' => string 'www.google.com' (length=14)
  'query' => string 'page=bla+bla' (length=12)
```

you can then validate the `host` array element and ignore the `query`

```
$clean_url = parse_url($url)['host'];
```